# Missing return statement error (Reference Based List)

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

I'm trying to make a reference based sorted list, but every time I try to compile it, I get this error.

"missing return statement"

I don't really understand why I'm getting it, though it seems to be an issue with my locateIndex methods

This is my code

```
public class SortedListReferenceBased extends ListReferenceBased
{

    public int index;
    public int numItems;
    public Node head;

    public SortedListReferenceBased()
    // creates an empty list
    {
        numItems = 0;
        head = null;
    }  // end default constructor


    public void add(String item) throws ListException
    // Inserts item into its proper position in a sorted list
    // Throws an exception if the item connot be placed on the list
    {
        try
        {
            locateIndexToAdd(item);
            super.add(index,item);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new ListException("Add to List failed:  " + e.toString());
        }

    }


    public void remove(String item) throws ListException
    // Removes the item from a sorted list.
    // Throws an exception if the item is not found.
    {
        try
        {
            locateIndexToRemove(item);
            super.remove(index);
            // YOUR CODE WILL BE HERE...
            // REQUIREMENT: USE "locateIndex(String item)" method.
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new ListException("Remove " + item.toString() + " from List failed:  " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public int locateIndexToAdd(String item)
    // Returns the position where the item belongs or exists in a sorted list;
    // item and the list are unchanged.
    {
        int stop = 0;
        index = 0;
        while (index <= numItems && stop == 0)
        {
            Object curr = super.get(index);
            String current  = curr.toString();
            if (item.compareTo(current) > 0)
                index++;
            else
            {
                stop = 1;
                return index;
            }
        }

    }

    public int locateIndexToRemove(String item)
    // Returns the position where the item belongs or exists in a sorted list;
    // item and the list are unchanged.
    {
        int found = 0;
        index = 0;
        while (index <= numItems && found == 0)
        {
            Object curr = super.get(index);
            String current  = curr.toString();
            if (item.compareTo(current) == 0)
            {
                found = 1;
                return index;
            }
            else
            {
                index ++;
            }
        }
        if (found == 0)
            System.out.println("Item not found");

    }

}  // end SortedListReferenceBased
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, there are several things you could improve in order to attract good answers:  
1. Please add a tag to tell us which language this is.  
2. Tell us where in your code the problem is (usually your compiler will tell you at what line the error occurred)  
3. Remove everything from your example that is not necessary to demonstrate your problem, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

This method indeed is missing a `return` statement

```
public int locateIndexToRemove(String item)
// Returns the position where the item belongs or exists in a sorted list;
// item and the list are unchanged.
{
    int found = 0;
    index = 0;
    while (index <= numItems && found == 0)
    {
        Object curr = super.get(index);
        String current  = curr.toString();
        if (item.compareTo(current) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            return index;
        }
        else
        {
            return index ++; // or here
        }
    }
    if (found == 0)
        System.out.println("Item not found");

    return index; // <-- the missing return statement.
}
```

that there is one here:

```
        if (item.compareTo(current) == 0)
    {
        found = 1;
        return index;
    }
```

is not enough, because what happens if the `if` statement returns false, there isn't a value to return anymore and thus the compiler will complain about a missing return statement.

Comment: To expand on this, when you mark a method as non-void (aka, it returns a value), you need to make sure it ALWAYS returns a value, no matter what.  `locateIndexToAdd` also needs a return statement at the end

Answer (score 0):

WonderWorld answered it right.
When you are specifying in your locateIndexToRemove method signature that your return type must be int , well you must be returning int.
Whats happening in this method is that either your if and else statement inside your while loop of locateIndexToRemove is not running or your while itself is not running making it impossible for the locateIndexToRemove method to return an int value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this'll work for you,

```
    int stop = 0;
    index = 0;
    while (index < numItems && stop == 0)
    {
        Object curr = super.get(index);
        String current  = curr.toString();
        if (item.compareTo(current) > 0)
            index++;
        else
        {
            stop = 1;
        }
    }
    return index;
```

> and I think you must increment and decrements "numItems" when adding and removing items.

Comment: There is also the return in "public int locateIndexToRemove(String item)" that you need to add to your answer.